# Can you get user input with turtle.write?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I want to ask the user a question using turtle.write and get input. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html#turtle.write) you can't get an input with `turtle.write`

you could use [turtle.textinput](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.textinput), ex:

```
turtle.textinput('My app', 'What is your name?')
```